# Sort a database with a href in HTML and php

Tags: php, html

Hi I have searched for a simple script that helps med sort my database with php in HTML href link. All I have found is too complicated. My database is holding filenames and who uploaded an image file and what date it was added. It won't sort the images by date or uploader. I can see in the browsers address field that it changes the link value.
Could you please help me?

```
<?php

include ("includes/localdbc.php");
?>
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="sv"><!--Här bestäms språket-->
<head><!--Övrig information till dokumentet -->
<meta charset = "utf-8"><!--teckenuppsättningen för att hantera svenska tecken-->
<title>Fotoalbum</title><!--Dokumentets titel-->


<link rel ="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href= "stilmall.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen">


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
{$(".fancybox").fancybox();
helpers : {
title: {
type: 'inside'}}
$("a[href$='.jpg']").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<section class="arbetsyta">
<?php
include ("includes/nav.php");
?>
<div>          
<h2> Välkommen!</h2>
<p class="mellanrubrik">Här kan du ladda upp dina foton</p>
<p class="stycke">Bilden ska vara en jpg och inte vara större än 200kb</p>
</div>
<div class="formyta"><!-- formulär för uppladdning av bilder -->
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="200000" /> <!-- 200K max storlek -->
<label for="file">Filnamn:</label><br />
<input type="file" name="file" class="textfalt" /><br />
<label>Beskrivning:</label><br />
<input type="text" title="beskrivning" name="beskrivning" class="textfalt" /><br />
<label>Uppladdad av:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="uppladdare" class="textfalt" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Ladda upp" class="knapp"/>  
</form>
</div>
//Upload images script
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] ==
"image/pjpeg")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)) {
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
echo "Felmeddelande: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
} else {

if (file_exists("bilder/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " finns redan. Välj ett annat filnamn.";

} else {

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "bilder/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

$storedfile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$thumbnail = "thumb_" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

$width_thumbnail = 350;
$height_thumbnail = 100;

list($width_thumbnail_orig, $height_thumbnail_orig) = getimagesize('bilder/' .$storedfile);

$ratio_orig = $width_thumbnail_orig / $height_thumbnail_orig;                                      


if ($width_thumbnail / $height_thumbnail > $ratio_orig) {
$width_thumbnail = $height_thumbnail * $ratio_orig;
$height_thumbnail = $width_thumbnail / $ratio_orig;
} else {
$height_thumbnail = $width_thumbnail / $ratio_orig;
$width_thumbnail = $height_thumbnail * $ratio_orig;
                        }


$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width_thumbnail, $height_thumbnail);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('bilder/' . $storedfile);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_thumbnail, $height_thumbnail, $width_thumbnail_orig, $height_thumbnail_orig);

imagejpeg($image_p, 'bilder/' . $thumbnail);




$beskrivning = $_POST["beskrivning"];
$beskrivning = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $beskrivning);

$uppladdare = $_POST["uppladdare"];
$uppladdare = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $uppladdare);

$datum = $_POST["datum"];
$datum = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $datum);

$sql="INSERT INTO foto (filnamn, beskrivning, uppladdare)
VALUES
('$storedfile','$beskrivning','$uppladdare')";

if (!mysqli_query($dbc,$sql))
{
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbc));
}

}
}
} 
else {
// Här hamnar man om det inte är JPEG/bildfil för stor
echo "Ej JPEG/Bildfilen större än 200kb.";
} //End upload script
?>


<div id="sort">
<?php    
$order="";
if(isset($_GET['order'])) {
if($_GET['order']=="uppladdare"){
$order = "ORDER BY uppladdare";
}
if($_GET['order']=="datum"){
$order = "ORDER BY datum DESC";
}
}                     


$query ="SELECT * FROM foto $order";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
// It is here something good should be written  ?>
<p class="nav">Sortera bilder:</p>
<a class="nav" href="medlem.php?order=uppladdare">Uppladdad av:</a><span style="padding-left:30px;"></span>                           
<a class="nav" href="medlem.php?order=datum">Datum:</a>
</div>  

<div id="bildyta">
<?php //Images shows
$query = "SELECT * FROM foto";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Fel vid SQL-fråga');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$storedfile = $row['filnamn'];
$beskrivning = $row['beskrivning'];
$uppladdare =$row['uppladdare'];
$datum = $row['datum'];
$bildtext = "$beskrivning" ." " ."Uppladdad av:"." " ."$uppladdare"." "."$datum"; 

echo "<a class='fancybox' title='$bildtext' href='bilder/$storedfile'><img src='bilder/thumb_$storedfile' alt='$beskrivning'/></a>\n" . "&nbsp" . "&nbsp"; 
}
mysqli_close($dbc);

?>
 </div> 
</section>                           
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try echoing the $query ?

Comment: Yes I have tried different ways. If  I echo $rows = $order it will only repeats ORDER BY uppladdare so many times there are rows in the database. The same happens if I only echo $order.

Comment: can you echo $query ="SELECT * FROM foto $order"; ?

Comment: Can you post the table structure of foto  ?

Comment: My fields in my database with table foto is: id, filnamn, uppladdare, beskrivning, datum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you replace this from `div id="sort"` in your code with the below one

```
<div id="sort">
<?php /*?><?php    
$order="";
if(isset($_GET['order'])) {
    if($_GET['order']=="uppladdare"){
        $order = "ORDER BY uppladdare";
    }
    if($_GET['order']=="datum"){
        $order = "ORDER BY datum DESC";
    }
}                     
$query ="SELECT * FROM foto $order";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
// It is here something good should be written  ?><?php */?>
<p class="nav">Sortera bilder:</p>
<a class="nav" href="medlem.php?order=uppladdare">Uppladdad av:</a><span style="padding-left:30px;"></span>                           
<a class="nav" href="medlem.php?order=datum">Datum:</a>
</div>  

<div id="bildyta">
<?php //Images shows
$order="";
if(isset($_GET['order'])) {
    if($_GET['order']=="uppladdare"){
        $order = "ORDER BY uppladdare";
    }
    if($_GET['order']=="datum"){
        $order = "ORDER BY datum DESC";
    }
}                     
$query ="SELECT * FROM foto $order";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Fel vid SQL-fråga');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $storedfile = $row['filnamn'];
    $beskrivning = $row['beskrivning'];
    $uppladdare =$row['uppladdare'];
    $datum = $row['datum'];
    $bildtext = "$beskrivning" ." " ."Uppladdad av:"." " ."$uppladdare"." "."$datum"; 
    echo "<a class='fancybox' title='$bildtext' href='bilder/$storedfile'><img src='bilder/thumb_$storedfile' alt='$beskrivning'/></a>\n" . "&nbsp" . "&nbsp"; 
}
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
 </div> 
</section>                           
</body>
</html>
```

and also one of your if loop is not properly closed. please put a `}` to close after //End upload script

Comment: Now you will get the result from the query as rows of result ...i hope this resolves your issue ?

Comment: I have a selection where I have the images already shown and I have a fancybox plugin and all that are function well.
The code is too long to post here. I have tried your code but it doesn't sort the images.

Comment: my code, just echo's the result from db. you need to change the above code to your your needs ..

Comment: How can I post the hole file? Starting a new thread? It is too long for a comment

Comment: can you retry the answer i have posted and tell me what exact error are you getting ?

Comment: is this PHP page saved by the name medlem.php ?

Comment: yes it is called medlem.php. Should I use any kind of Ajax?

Comment: can you retry the answer i have posted and tell me what exact error are you getting ? replace from <div id="sort"> till end of file

Comment: You have made my day! Thank you! When I replaced your suggestion in the last while loop it worked!! The loop was closed, but I missed it when I edit the code here, sorry for that.

Comment: Do I need 15 reputation before I can rate this? I really would like to give my thumb up :)

Comment: the issue is, what you were doing was that, you were not passing the ordering veritable into the sql which was displaying.

Comment: yes, you need 15 reputation for that but you can mark it as correct answer by clicking the tick mark